# Start and stop my application when my PC starts and stops?

Tags: asp.net, windows, windows-services

How can I make my application installed in my PC to start(ie., to popup for username and password) when I logged in to my PC, so that I can provide my username and password to the application and log in to it,similarly like gtalk that popsup for username and password once logged in to PC?

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention asp.net as the tag (iis dugh?). Well you just need to

[Run the application at Windows startup](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial151_Run-the-application-at-Windows-startup.html)

and then do whatever.... also....

[Placing Your C# Application in the System Tray](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3336751)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your application to windows startup.
http://en.allexperts.com/q/Windows-XP-3282/Add-program-start.htm
This link will give you some information.

Answer (score 0):

I saw ur tag on window service, but if your program is developed in windows application and there is no need for a separate window service program.

Maybe u want to try using the registry?

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Adding a program to this registry will allow it to run on startup.

However if security is concerned, I would encourage using window service then.
Be sure to set your window service startup type to Automatic, user account will be Local System, and check allow user interaction. In the code for service start, launch your program.

Of cause this method launch once your computer starts. If a user logout and login again, it will not be launched again. Need additional code to tidy up on this part

Answer (score 0):

Just place the shortcut of your application in \Start Menu\Program\Startup folder regardless of where your application is installed.